# I populated a Mongoose Model, but when I reference it later it isn't populated

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I was writing code for a simple web application with CRUD functionality.
I tried to add a comment section, and came up with a model for the 'formula' schema. You can think of 'formula' as the equivalent to a 'blog post'.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const commentModel = require('./comment.js');

const formulaSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    creator: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    formula: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    comments: [ 
        { 
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'Comment' 
        } 
    ]
})

const formulaModel = mongoose.model('formula', formulaSchema);

module.exports = formulaModel;
```

The code displayed above is for the formula model.

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const commentSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        enum: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
})

const commentModel = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);

module.exports = commentModel;
```

The code displayed above is for the comment model.

Whenever I add a comment, I add it to the formula model and then populate it.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {formulaSchema, commentSchema} = require('../schemas.js');
const formulaModel = require('../models/formula.js');
const commentModel = require('../models/comment.js');
const AppError = require('../AppError');

const wrapAsync = require('../functions/wrappers/wrap');
const verifyID = require('../functions/validations/verifyID');


const verifyComment = (req, res, next) => {
    const { error } = commentSchema.validate(req.body);
    if(error) {
        const msg = error.details.map(el => el.message);
        throw new AppError(400, msg);
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

router.post('/:id/comments', verifyComment, wrapAsync(async function(req, res, next) {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const theFormula = await formulaModel.findById(id);
    const comment = new commentModel(req.body.comment);
    await theFormula.comments.push(comment);
    await theFormula.populate('comments');
    await theFormula.save();
    await comment.save();
    
    //console.log(theFormula.comments[0].name);
    
    res.redirect(`/details/${id}`);
}))

module.exports = router;
```

By console.logging, I recognized that the model was populated correctly:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("613f4ef3677593f9173e60c5"),
  name: 'The Ultimate Addition',
  creator: 'Anonymous',
  formula: '1+1=2',
  comments: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("613f4f09677593f9173e60cb"),
      name: 'The First Comment',
      body: '#1. Do not comment bullshit.',
      rating: 1,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("613f4fcff98c95a4af3f6722"),
      name: 'The Second Comment',
      body: '222222222222',
      rating: 2,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("613f50f24d97ad45daa850b2"),
      name: 'The Third Comment',
      body: '33333333333',
      rating: 3,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("613f52f9c0b6ad6247ad7d6a"),
      name: 'The Fourth Comment',
      body: '4444$$$$',
      rating: 3,
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  __v: 5
}
```

However, when I access it later, it seems like it isn't populated:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {formulaSchema, commentSchema} = require('../schemas.js');
const formulaModel = require('../models/formula.js');

const wrapAsync = require('../functions/wrappers/wrap');
const verifyID = require('../functions/validations/verifyID');


router.get('/:id', verifyID, wrapAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const {theFormula} = res.locals;
    // console.log(theFormula);
    res.render('detail', {theFormula});
}))

module.exports = router;
```

By console.logging, I get results like:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("613f4ef3677593f9173e60c5"),
  name: 'The Ultimate Addition',
  creator: 'Anonymous',
  formula: '1+1=2',
  comments: [
    new ObjectId("613f4f09677593f9173e60cb"),
    new ObjectId("613f4fcff98c95a4af3f6722"),
    new ObjectId("613f50f24d97ad45daa850b2"),
    new ObjectId("613f52f9c0b6ad6247ad7d6a"),
    new ObjectId("613f531c5065ca83ad450dea")
  ],
  __v: 5
}
```

Why doesn't my model *stay populated*? I mean, it does save all other changes via the comment section.

Comment: I figured out the problem. You have to populate in the place where you want to render it.
There's no need to call .populate() in the 3rd chunk of code.
You have to call .populate() in the 5th chunk of code instead.

Comment: This got me wondering - does mongooseModel.populate() have only temporary effect?
I think the answer to this question is 'yes', looking at the mongo database directly.